# How to do write-behind async tasks in Actix-Web?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, actix-web, rust-actix

In a web environment with Actix-Web I want to write behind data to a database, async so the request is not held up. This could also be calling a webhook or calling an API to send an email.

With Scala I would create a queue and use a thread pool (e.g. with ForkJoin) to fire and forget a task.

How would I do this in Rust with Actix-Web? (Actix actors?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use [`actix_web::rt::spawn`](https://docs.rs/actix-rt/1.1.1/actix_rt/fn.spawn.html) to execute an `async` function that runs independently.

Comment: Thanks! Without waiting, does it execute? How do I control the number of threads vs. the queue length?

Comment: You do not need to `.await` it if thats what you're asking. This will run it on the same async runtime that is handling your actix-web endpoints. It does not use a separate threadpool or queue.

Comment: Is there a way to use a separate thread pool? Does it have a queue or does every spawn call directly lead to a new thread? I cant find anything in the documentation.

Comment: There is no explicit queue or new threads when using this method. Rust's async is a type of *cooperative multitasking* or *green-threads* as other languages call it. By default I believe Actix creates N threads on an N-core CPU. The runtime runs your tasks for the whole web server, this `spawn` call just adds another task onto the pile to run.

Comment: If you want to configure your own threadpool and your own queue, you'll have to reach outside the Actix ecosystem.

Comment: Thanks for that information, appreciated.

Comment: @KingOfCoders you might also be interested in `SyncArbiter` https://actix.rs/book/actix/sec-6-sync-arbiter.html